# Problem with forcing with perfect trees

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I've been reading the section on Forcing with Perfect Trees in Jech's *Set Theory*. The notion of forcing consists of all perfect trees $T\subseteq Seq(\{0,1\})$, where $p$ is stronger than $q$ if $p\subset q$.

Now, let $G$ be generic set of perfect trees. Define $f=\bigcup\{s:(\forall p\in G)s\in p\}.$ Let us see why $f$ is indeed a function. For each $n<\omega$ let $D_n$ be the set of all perfect trees $p$ such that $s\upharpoonright n$ is constant for $s\in p$, then $D_n$ is dense, and thus we can pick $p_n\in G\cap D_n$, then it is easy to prove that $f=\bigcup_n s_n$, where $s_n\in p_n$ is the only element of $p_n$ of length $n$.

Next the author states that $V[G]=V[f]$ with no argument. So my question is, why does this hold?

As the generic filter is minimal over the ground model $V$, that is, for any set of ordinals $X\in V[G]$ we have that $X\in V$ or $G\in V[X]$, it suffices to show that $f\notin V$. I have tried two approaches to prove this:

- Showing that $f:\omega\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ is a Cohen real.
- Proving that for any filter $G'$ of perfect trees such that $f\upharpoonright n\in p$ for all $p\in G'$ we have that $G'$ is generic over $V$.

However, I think the first approach is wrong, and I have no idea on how to prove the second one.

Thanks.

Comment: To the question in the title, most certainly not. Adding one Sacks real doesn't add any Cohen reals, and a Cohen real don't add a Sacks real.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I claim that $G$ is definable from $f$; indeed, $G$ consists precisely of the ground model trees containing the generic branch $f$. Of course, every tree in $G$ contains the branch $f$ by definition. Now assume that there is a tree $T\notin G$ containing the branch $f$. Let $S\in G$ be a condition forcing that $T$ contains $f$. Since $T$ is not in $G$, there must be a node $x\in S\setminus T$. Let's denote by $S_x$ the induced subtree of $S$, i.e. the set of nodes in $S$ compatible with $x$. Then $S_x$ is a perfect tree, it strengthens $S$ and it forces that the generic branch goes through $x$. But this means that $S_x$ cannot force that $T$ contains the generic branch. Contradiction.

Comment: In the second part of his book, Jech makes a lot of these jumps, for example in the proof of the covering lemma he skips the difficult part by outlining it as "not very difficult". He does admit to do that, though, in the introduction. So it's not surprising. This book is more of a reference, and you really have to study on your own most of the time.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I understand that not every argument can be completely spelled out. On the other hand, I feel there is a difference between skipping a part of a proof involving major machinery (like the covering lemma, although I'll have to take your word for that), and skipping a 5 line argument like this one.

Comment: I took Magidor's word for it; and later when he gave a course on large cardinals that outline took us about three weeks to finish. But the Magidor paper is quite readable and the proof is very well written there (although it's using a whole other machinery from the paper to cut short the covering lemma proof; but in the book he doesn't talk about that sort of machinery so it should be long).

Comment: All the above been said, I still find Jech to be one of the canonical books for modern set theory, and I generally find it well written, even when he skips and omits parts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree with all of that.

Comment: @MihaHabič, I'm afraid there is something wrong here. In $V[f]$, the set of all perfect trees having $f$ as a branch is not a filter. Consider $T_0=\{s:s\subseteq f$ or the least $n$ with $s(n)\neq f(n)$ is even$\}$, and $T_1=\{s:s\subseteq f$ or the least $n$ with $s(n)\neq f(n)$ is odd$\}$, then $T_0\cap T_1=\{f\upharpoonright n:n\in\mathbb N\}$, which is not a perfect tree.

Comment: Your error is that you're considering $T$ fixed. $S_x$ does force that $T$ containd the generic branch; $S_x$ modifies $T$.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena What I meant was that $G$ consists of the *ground model* Sacks conditions having the generic branch. Of course, having the branch allows me to define new trees, like your $T_0$ and $T_1$, but those won't be in the ground model.

Answer (score 3):

Miha's answer is the answer to your main question, but let me just answer the question in the title: no Sacks real is ever Cohen.

For example, consider the tree of all sequences never containing "00." This is clearly a perfect tree, so corresponds to a condition in Sacks forcing; but any real satisfying this condition will not be Cohen, because the set of reals containing "00" is dense open for Cohen forcing.

In general, it is open dense in the Cohen sense to fall off of any perfect tree whose set of branches has empty interior in Cantor space; and the set of such trees is dense open in the Sacks sense. So no Sacks generic real will ever be Cohen generic.

Comment: Couldn't one also argue from the minimality of Sacks reals? Cohen reals should imply an abundance of intermediate models, while Sacks reals have none.

Comment: Yes, but it's much more work to show that a Sacks real is minimal than it is to make the argument above.